# "Косатка" и "касатка"

Tags: орфография

Есть дельфин косатка. Название произошло от слова "коса", на которую похож спинной плавник самцов. Но очень часто в литературе я встречаю написание "к**а**сатка". Почему так? Допустимы оба варианта? Но, если да, то от какого слова может происходить вариант через А?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант касатка явно происходит от смешения с ласковым обращением у женщине.
Менее вероятно - с названием ласточки или цветка (касатик - ирис). Само же по себе касатка - тоже, вероятно, искаженное "косатка". Считается, что у ласточки раздвоенный "косой" хвост.

Таким образом все касатки и косатки - этимологические родственники, и колебания в написании объясняются не только безграмотностью пишущего.

Answer (score -1):

Ласточка(касатка) имеет длинный хвост, поэтому "поэтически настроенный" славянин теоретически мог назвать эту птичку с длинными как у замужней женщины (2шт потому что) косами, как-нибудь ласково, типа "касатка".
А вот с косой речной и косаткой всё не так просто, есть глагол *коs* ("резать" - в переводе на наш великий и могучий, корни его еврейские), и вот поэтому режем траву мы косой, и воду режет коса речная (морская), косатка же режет волну морскую ;((